# O(n) or faster algorithm for sorting a list by levenshtein distance?

Tags: algorithm, function, sorting, hash, levenshtein-distance

Is there an O(n) or faster algorithm for sorting a list by levenshtein distance? I've looked some solutions on SO, but all of them invoke traditional sorting. Now, suppose you just sum the bytes of your input: you'll get hash keys that are pretty much sorted by their levenshtein distance. For example, I took a set of random strings and computed their hashes by byte summation:

```
[ { hash: 2826, val: 'LKAMFKLFUAHUHAUHAUHAU:ANGONEGANAILFJAL:' },
  { hash: 2829, val: 'LKAMFKLFLFUAHUAHUHAUAHANGONEGANAILFJAL:' },
  { hash: 2845, val: 'LKAMFKLFLFAKAKKAKAfiO:ANGONEGANAILFJAL:' },
  { hash: 3064, val: 'LKAMFKLFKKKlaNflanfiO:ANGONEGANAILFJAL:' },
  { hash: 3092, val: 'LKAMFKLFLFklaNflanfiO:ANGONEGANAILFJAL:' },
  { hash: 3203, val: 'LKAMFKLFLFklaNflanfiRSRSRSRSRRNAILFJAL:' },
  { hash: 3249, val: 'LKNFUU{N{UAFN{NF}FNPNF{FN{APNF{WNFF{NF' },
  { hash: 3843, val: 'ddddddddddaaaaaaaaaddddddddddaaaaaaaaaa' },
  { hash: 3858, val: 'safndjnjcmxn,znv,mnm,n,mvnm,vn,mznv,mvv' },
  { hash: 3934, val: 'nngnangngdsgsangnanwns.mnv.nv.xnjvnsf.,' },
  { hash: 3972, val: 'adadsadadsadadadsadsadadsadsadadsadsada' },
  { hash: 3992, val: 'adsadadadsadasdasdafadfasfdsafsafasfafd' },
  { hash: 4041, val: 'asfdsafasdfsafafasdfasdfafsdfdasfasfasf' },
  { hash: 4047, val: 'kkkkkkkkkkkdddddddddkkkkkkkkkkddddddddd' },
  { hash: 4058, val: 'jfjfjfjfjfjfjfjfjfjfjfjfjfjfjfjfjfjfjfj' },
  { hash: 4081, val: 'ioudnjkanfjfhjhfjhakfshfkjhdajhkjafhkjf' },
  { hash: 4082, val: 'ioudnjkanfjfhjhfjhakfshfkjhdakhkjafhkjf' },
  { hash: 4082, val: 'oisdnkbgjkbajkgkbgkjbkklgjklsbkbfkjafas' },
  { hash: 4090, val: 'ioudnjsanfjfhjhfjhakfshfkjhdakhkjafhkjf' },
  { hash: 4099, val: 'asldfjlkcmclmasldkkjflksajflkjaljfljlfa' },
  { hash: 4101, val: 'sidfjlasjflijflijlfjliafjdlifjlijfiljfl' },
  { hash: 4105, val: 'iousnjsanfjfhjhfjhakfshfkjhdakhkjafhkjf' },
  { hash: 4125, val: 'iousnjsanfjfhlhfjuakfshkkjhdakhkjafhkjf' },
  { hash: 4128, val: 'sadnfjnfjnjfnjsdfnjafnjkfnkfnjkansdfjkn' },
  { hash: 4143, val: 'dnsfanfjknasfjklnaskfnkfnklafnjkfnkldsn' },
  { hash: 4150, val: 'dskfoisandginsgnlgn:nglngbtbiybuburubsu' },
  { hash: 4155, val: 'afadfsfsfsdfffsfsfsfsdfsfsfsdfsfsfsfsfs' },
  { hash: 4166, val: 'kjdkljkljkljlkjkljlkjlkjlkjlkjljlkjljlk' },
  { hash: 4211, val: 'jsanjnvjksnfkjsanfuiawngingiuilugniugng' },
  { hash: 4229, val: 'kllnlknlknklnklnlnlknknklnlnlnklnlknlkn' },
  { hash: 4238, val: 'lsniorhgpwoiqutoiuieofnionofnoinfonfioa' },
  { hash: 4349, val: 'iasfioehwoptqpoituopqwtuoquweporuqiorur' },
  { hash: 4374, val: 'ioequroiqwuroiuriouroiuopriuprouqpourrq' },
  { hash: 4377, val: 'iiuouoiuoiuouoiuuououoiuououoiuououoiuo' } ]
```

The result is nearly sorted, which means insertion sort could complete the job really fast ([see](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/)).

If such crude experiment provided those results, then there is certainly some solution which SO is missing on it's answers. Which could it be?

Comment: Those strings don't look particularly random.

Comment: @JimMischel Not randomly generated, just random in the sense of taken from nowhere. Some are similar in order to illustrate the point.

Comment: @Blastfurnace What do you mean? z levenshtein distance to any of those strings is probably the same.

Comment: @Blastfumace this has nothing to do with alphabetical sorting, please read about the levenshtein distance!

Comment: I think I may be missing the point of what you are doing. Consider my comments retracted and have a nice day.

Comment: How can a sorting algo be faster than O(n)?

Comment: What point are you trying to illustrate?

Comment: @JimMischel What the heck are guys you serious? Are you even reading the question? I'm clearly asking if there's a proper algorithm to sort by levenshtein distance that's O(n) or faster, and I have showed the basis for one that is O(n)

Comment: @Blastfurnace no problems mate have a nice day too (:

Comment: Can you add levenshtein distances for them strings too?

Comment: Take Hash values (3858, 3934, 3972), are respective values in increasing order? so, I presumed their `levenshtein distances` might be. Are they?

Comment: Sorry I'm still not sure what you mean? Do you mean computing hash(3858), hash(3934), hash(3972)? And if so, why?

Comment: I picked them from your list above; 9, 10 & 11 entry respectively.

Comment: `Levenshtein distances` is the edit distance between 2 strings (it may include insertion and deletion). It only happens that 2 strings which are almost the same has very close sum of character code, but the converse is not always true.

Comment: @nhahtdh The converse is not always true, but many times it is, so it can be used to make a nearly sorted array as I just illustrated.

Comment: @Dokkat: Then what is the exact order that you want? (The goal of the actual sorted list) Without calculate the exact distance, how would you arrive at the actual list?

Comment: Consider you've got 3 strings: ABC, ABD and ABE. Exactly what order do you expect them to be in after sorting by Levenstein/edit distance? There are 6 possible and completely equivalent orders for these 3 strings.

Comment: Levenshstein distance is not a property of a string - it's a relation between two strings. You can't "sort by Levenshtein distance" without a reference string you're comparing all your strings to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discussion below is my long-winded way of saying that your idea (as I understand it) cannot work in the general case. The reason? Because the Levenshtein distance between two strings of length N chould be N, but the strings have identical checksums. A reversed string, for example. Furthermore, the checksum difference between two strings with a Levenshtein distance of 1 can be 255 (or 65,536 in Unicode). With a range like that, "almost sorting," even if you could do it somehow (see below), isn't going to gain you much.

So you've noticed a correlation between a simple checksum and Levenshtein distance. It's an obvious relationship. If the Levenshtein distance between two strings is small, then those two strings contain mostly the same characters. So computation of the simple checksum will result in very similar values. Sometimes.

As somebody else pointed out, though, the reverse isn't true. The strings `abcdef` and `fedcba` have identical checksums, but their Levenshtein distance is fairly large for such a short string.

This isn't true only of reversals. Consider, for example, the string `00000000`. The string `0000000~` will have a much larger checksum than `11111111`, even though the Lev. distance is much smaller.

I think you'll find in the general case that the relationship between checksum and Lev. distance is ... sometimes coincidental. But let's ignore that particular problem and move on to your hypothesis about the sorting.

As I understand it (and, truthfully, your question isn't entirely clear on this point), you want to sort a list of strings based on their Levenshtein distance. You don't say distance from *what*, but I'll assume that somewhere you have a starting string, `S`, a bunch of other strings `[S1, S2, S3, etc.]`, and you want to sort that list of other strings by Lev. distance from `S`.

Your hypothesis appears to be that computing a simple checksum for each string will allow you to do that sort more quickly.

The problem is that once you've computed the checksums, *you have to sort them*. And that's going to take `O(n log n)` time with a traditional comparison sort (and in any case, at least `O(n)` time if you have a special-purpose sort). And once you've got that supposedly-almost-ordered list, you have to compute the Lev. distances anyway, and then rearrange the list order to reflect the real distances. But what's the point?

You have to compute the Lev. distances anyway, and you will spend *at least* `O(n)` time sorting *something*. Why go to the extra trouble of computing and sorting checksums when you can more quickly just compute the Lev. distances and sort those?

Answer (score 1):

The O(n log n) bound is for a particular kind of sorting, based on comparisons on an ordered type.

In this case, your ordering is based on a simple unsigned integer value with (depending on the data you're dealing with) probably a fairly small bound. In this case, your options are...

1. If the maximum distance is small enough, create an array of (initially null) list head pointers. The array subscript is the distance. Loop through your data to populate that array of lists, then extract all the data back out in order. If you're concerned about a lot of the head pointers in the array staying null (lots of distances that never occur) you can also build two double-linked lists into the array - one initially full list of unused items, one initially empty list of used items. That way, when you extract the data, you only have to look at those lists that have items in them.
2. Irrespective of the maximum distance, you can do the same thing with a hash table. If the table grows by a constant factor each time more space is needed, each insert takes O(1) time *amortized*. When you consider the whole loop, that becomes simply O(n) - not amortized any more - because of the way "amortized" is defined. A hash table is normally unordered, but you can cheat - the hash is the distance. A bit more cheating is probably needed to avoid making multiple passes when extracting data, but it shouldn't be too hard.

I don't see any benefit in trying to use checksums.

You can't beat O(n) if you want to sort the data because you may need to move every single item. Even if you just magically knew where to move each item to, doing those moves is O(n) anyway.

Also, even if the data was already in the correct order, simply computing the distances to confirm that is also O(n).

---

I'm getting a bit nervous, on second thoughts, because you can't just assign a Levenshtein distance to one string - it's relative to another.

If you want to build an index of strings so you can search for the "nearest" one, you should probably look at [this post about Vantage Point Trees on Steve Hanov's blog](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=130).

I doubt you'll get O(n) performance using that, though.